# C program that takes keyboard input and logs it into text file

Tags: c

the program below is to open tty and read from that file, and assign a file descriptor to that file. its suppose to assign the lowest file descriptor number available, but Ive included in my code an if statement that will detect an error. if(fd== -1). when I compile the program on an online compiler, it runs and shows error in opening the device, the value of fd_in is -1 and I don't understand why. when I compile in terminal, I get the warning "warning: return type of 'main' is not 'int' ". The program is suppose to then takes what it reads from the device and writes it into log.txt

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void  main(){
        int fd_in = open("/dev/ttys000", O_RDONLY);

        printf("The file descriptor is: %d \n", fd_in);
        if(fd_in == -1){
                printf("Error in opening device!\n");
                return;
        }
        int fd_out= open("log.txt", O_WRONLY);
        char buf[20];
        ssize_t bytes_read;

        while ((bytes_read = read(fd_in, buf, sizeof(buf))) > 0) {
                write(fd_out, buf, bytes_read );
        if(buf[0]== 'E'&& buf[1] == 'N' && buf[2] == 'D'){
        break;
        }
}
        int result = close(fd_in);
         if(result == -1){
                printf("Error in closing the device!\n");
        };

}
```

Comment: ⟼Remember, it's always important, *especially* when learning and asking questions on Stack Overflow, to keep your code as organized as possible. [Consistent indentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation_style) helps communicate structure and, importantly, intent, which helps us navigate quickly to the root of the problem without spending a lot of time trying to decode what's going on.

Comment: Did you read what you just posted? **warning: return type of 'main' is not 'int'** These errors help indicate the nature of your problem. Fix that first. Hint: `int main()` as an absolute minimum, and for formality, `return 0` at the end.